# Where is wildfly option when creating new openshift application from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, openshift, wildfly

Why is there no option for the new `wildfly` server when creating an application using the new openshift application wizard from eclipse?

In the New or existing OpenShift Application wizard if you click the Type combobox under the New Application group you will only have options for `jboss application server 7` and `jboss enterprise application platform 6`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently WildFly is a community cartridge, and as such does not show up if you run the rhc cartridges command, so it does not show up there either.  If you want to use wildfly, i would suggest using the web console or the rhc client for the time being, until it is officially available via those means.

Then you can go into the openshift tools for eclipse and select "use existing application" and it will clone it locally for you to work on.

Comment: follow https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBDS-2865 and https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-15476  - its new main feature in next version of openshift tools for eclipse.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am using git(my repo),maven and then deploy the created war with SFTP. Just wanted to check if working with the eclipse wizard would turn to out to be handier for me.

Comment: the only thing eclipse can't do right now is the initial application creation based on custom cartridge. SFTP/SCP you can do with the Deploy only server that also comes with JBoss tools.

Comment: @Max Rydahl Andersen not sure what you mean with the Deploy only server. (I  use 'WinSCP' as a SFTP client)